# keras model trained with python 2 gives nan values when predict functions is called using python 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras model which I've trained using python 2.7. This model is working correctly on python 2.7 when I try to predict. But when I try to predict using this model on python 3 it always predicts [[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]] values.

Here is the code I'm using to load model from json

```
def load_model_from_args(args):
    with open(args.json) as json_file:
        model = model_from_json(json_file.read())
        model.load_weights(args.weights)
        return model
```

Here is where I'm trying to get prediction

```
def get_emotion(features,model):
    predictions = model.predict(features)
    print(predictions)
    # [[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]]
    # the reset of the code
```

What is producing this type difference?

Comment: Most likely in how you compute `features` there might be a difference.

Comment: @nuric I've checked the values for `features` before calling predict function. they are the same for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following approach (not sure if it will work, but seems clean):

Get the weights of your model and save it with numpy:

```
#in 2.7
weights = model.get_weights()
np.save('weights27.npy', weights)
```

Create the model again via code in Python 3:

```
#in python 3, do no load the saved model, create a new one:
#same layers, same sizes, everything
...model code...
model3 = Model(...)
```

Load the weights into the model:

```
model3.set_weights(np.load('weights27.npy'))
```

Try using the model.

### Trying to work around the pickle problem:

```
weights = model.get_weights()
for i,w in enumerate(weights):
    np.save('weights-' + str(i) + ".npy", w, allow_pickle=False)
```

In python 3:

```
weights = []
for i in range(theTotalNumberOfSavedWeights):
    weights.append(np.load("weights-" + str(i) + ".npy", allow_pickle=False))

model2.set_weights(weights)
```

Comment: when I try your code I'm getting the following error
`np.save('weights27.npy', weights, allow_pickle=False)
  File "/xxx/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 511, in save
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/xxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 582, in write_array
    raise ValueError("Object arrays cannot be saved when "
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be saved when allow_pickle=False
`

Comment: still this is not solving the problem. I'm getting another type of error
`model.set_weights(np.load('weights27.npy'))
  File "/xxx/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 421, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/xxx/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 656, in read_array
    "to numpy.load" % (err,))
UnicodeError: Unpickling a python object failed: UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', b'\xb6\x99\xe2=n\x0e\xf5\xbc\xed\x177>\xeai!\xbd\x1f\xd5i\xbd%\x82k=\x04\xe6\n\xbe\xfe\x07\x81=\xf9F!\xbe/\x83\xd6\xbd\xaa|\x04>7\x17 >\xc2xJ\xbe\x7f}\x03=D?\
....
`

Comment: I've tryied with encoding="bytes" for `np.load` function but I'm getting `nan` values.

Comment: Try the new suggestion in my answer forcing `allow_pickle=False`.